# Can't execute C file in MinGW

Tags: c, mingw

I just started with C and MinGW today, first day of school. I'm trying to compile and execute some code stored in a notepad file that is stored in the appropriate folder. I can compile with gcc and when I call the list it shows me that the file has been reformatted to .exe, Yet when a type the name of the new .exe file it just say "Cannot Open". I've checked my code three times and it is exactly what the teacher wrote, so it shouldn't be a syntax error. Any ideas?

Comment: do you try to execute inside  mingw command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using mingw's bash shell, the current directory is not in the search path. So to execute a program in the current directory like `foo.exe`, you need to type `./foo` . Dot is the shorthand name for the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not very familiar with the prompt you could consider using an IDE like [Code::Blocks](http://codeblocks.org/).

Check out http://winlibs.com/ for instructions on how to use both command line and Code::Blocks.